# Using html5up template on Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, html

Hi I am new to Rails and web development in general. I want to implement a template that I have gotten from http://html5up.net/. The template is Big Picture.

Html5up.net uses a skel.js framework (first time using. Only knew about it when I downloaded the template) and I do not know how to incorporate it to my rails application (such as placing the scripts and stylesheets provided into which folder).

I have tried doing it via the default rails way, which is placing the stylesheets my /app/assets/stylesheets folder and also the javascripts in the javascript folder. But it did not turn out correctly. I suspect skel.min.js has its own way of finding the stylesheets.

As such, my web application looks unstyled currently.

Answer (score 2):

When lacking a gem for the assets pipeline, you can always include the source file inside `app/assets/javascripts` and the include it in the manifest.

Say you moved your skel.min.js into said folder. Now go to `application.js` and append the following line

```
//= require skel.min
```

and that's it. You must now call that file in the application layout file, using the `javascript_include_tag` helper.